# Using Like '%@mail%' in stored procedure

Tags: sql

If I try to call a stored procedure to check for mail addresses containing a @mail it fails because it sees  the @mail as a variable instead of a string literal

Comment: What SQL platform? Please provide an example of the stored procedure. Is `@mail` also included as a parameter at all?

Comment: I should have mentioned it is placed in an exec command

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
where email like '%' || @mail || '%'
```

`||` here is the standard operator for string concatenation.  This can very depending on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[Concat function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Email LIKE CONCAT('%',@Email,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a variable which holds the like @domainname placed it in the exec statement and it started working. So I guess the variable gets parced, the value is added to the query and its accepted as text in stead of searching for a variable